# R: plot saving and file name

Tags: r

I wrote a `dlply` function for plot printing via two variables `SITE` and `SP`. For this example, it prints me 715 plots, which have dynamic titles as you can see in my following code:

```
p <- dlply(SUBTOT_DATE, .(SITE, SP), function(x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(YEAR, SUMIA, group=SITE)) +
  geom_point(size=3, color="red2") +
  geom_line(size=1, color="red2") + 
  ggtitle(ggtitle(bquote(atop(.("Evolution de l'indice d'abondance"), atop(italic(.(paste(unique(as.character(x$SITE))," - ",unique(as.character(x$SP))))), ""))))) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Année") +
  ylab("Somme des IA") +
  theme(legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))
})
```

This is working great and I get the right plot titles (a paste of `SITE` and `SP`).

The next step I wrote is a loop for saving each plot with dynamic names composed of `SITE` and `SP`:

```
for( i in 1:length(p)) {
  filename<- paste(i, "_", unique(as.character(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE), "_",
                   unique(as.character(SUBTOT_DATE$SP)), ".png", sep="")
  png(file=filename)
  print(p[i])
  dev.off()
}
```

For some reason, I have to add a number in the file name (iteration number: `i`), otherwise there must be a conflict somewhere and my plots are not saved. This code is working and saving each graphs with a name composed of the two variables.

But the files names are wrong and doesn't follow the plot title. This is not surprising since there is no connexion between these two chunks.

I tried to put the saving command into the `dlply` function like this:

```
filename <- paste(unique(as.character(x$SITE)), "_", 
                  unique(as.character(x$SP)), ".png", sep="")
```

This should be working but it's not! For some reason all the plots saved are the same. For now I can't be sure it is saving the plot under the right name following the plot title.

Is there a syntax mistake I missed? Why is there only one plot saved multiple times? Following my experience with the conflict issue in the saving loop part, I’m guessing it should be answer by simply add a number in the file name (even if it can't save two plots under the same name because I have no doubles). But I don't know how to access iteration number in dlply to add it in the file name.

It is difficult for me to post reproducible data since every `dlply` iteration uses hundreds of rows.

Comment: `p` is list, you have to use the `[[` operator to extract single elements, i.e. `print(p[[i]])` (see `?"[["`)

Comment: since you're using ggplot, have a look into the ggsave function. It makes your life a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks zelite, i wasn't aware of this function and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rcs mentioned, you should change your printing loop to

```
for( i in 1:length(p)) {
  filename<- paste(i, "_", unique(as.character(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE), "_",
                   unique(as.character(SUBTOT_DATE$SP)), ".png", sep="")
  png(file=filename)
  print(p[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

The reason is that `p` is a list and you want to extract each plot in the list, not a list of plots. When using '[' with lists, you always get a list back.

Comment: I solved my problem with ggsave(),  but thanks for the info anyway!